# S/MIME: signed mails with disclaimer from mail filter/mailscanner?

Tags: email, certificate, smime

We have a Mailscanner, which scans incoming and outgoing mails and add a small disclaimer (Mail was checked for Viruses... bla bla bla).

So far i can add a disclaimer without signing the mail, or sign emails without adding the disclaimer.
Is there a way if if sign mails with an certificate, to still be able to add this disclaimer?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your email is S/MIME signed, you cannot add a disclaimer after signing the message. Adding a disclaimer after signing the message either invalidates the signature (i.e., the signature no longer validates) or the message is no longer a valid S/MIME message. One possible solution would be that the disclaimer service extracts the signed message and adds it as an attached message (content type message/rfc822) to a new message with the disclaimer. The same problem happens when using PGP/MIME signing since this is kind of similar to S/MIME signing. If you sign a message with PGP/INLINE, then you can add additional parts since PGP/INLINE signed individual message parts. The resulting message however is partly signed since the disclaimer is not signed so it's up to the client how to handle partly signed messages.